# Qcompleter to search in multiple columns of database for completion

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qcompleter

I am writing a software i which i want to search in two columns of sqlite3 database and get show the suggestions for auto complete or to select the item just like in medical store software. but i am unable to search in multiple columns using Qcompleter

i would really appreciate if anyone can help